# Simulating a BLE Pairing Mode on ESP32

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32

I've been working on a device that includes an ESP32. I set up a secure GATT server similar to the Secure Gatt Server Example with a custom service with Man in the Middle (MITM) based encryption. Currently pairing setup is Just Works, and when a client connects to the device they are prompted to pair and thus are bonded with key exchange (although it looks like Justworks disables MITM when I did more investigation for this question).

We do not have any real IO except for one button on the device, but I would like to limit pairing to a certain window of time after the Pairing button is pressed, or to have a "pairing mode" that the device enters (I have worked on another device that may have more of a classic pairing mode that was easier to work with). I know that's not explicitly part of the IDF API, but I'm looking for some guidance on how to approach something like a "pairing mode."

Would setting the IO capability to `ESP_IO_CAP_IO` work for using a button for the Yes/No?  I don't see anything relevant in the documentation about how to configure this.  In fact [the enum](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/03d78e7afbec57c30eb3dc58df9b90b3a8108483/components/bt/bluedroid/api/include/api/esp_gap_ble_api.h#L65) does not appear elsewhere in the IDF sourcecode, nor does the mentioned relevant file `stack/btm_api.h` help.

Is there a way to disable / enable pairing on command?  Would it be some type of change to advertising?